How to be sure that the body has a height before running a script
I want to execute this script within the astro framework to adjust the placement of my footer at the end of the page if the page is shorter than the viewport (if there is a better way tell me, but it's not the problem here):
    window.onload = function () {
        const footer = document.querySelector('footer')
        if (!footer) return
        const bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight
        const windowHeight = window.innerHeight
        if (bodyHeight < windowHeight) {
            footer.style.position = 'absolute'
            footer.style.bottom = '0'
            footer.style.width = '100%'
        }
    }

But because it's asynchronous document.body.clientHeight is equal to 0 9 times on 10 and window.onload handler change nothing. I also tried body.onload but same thing.
Here is my crappy hotfix:
    window.onload = function () {
        const footer = document.querySelector('footer')
        if (!footer) return
        footer.style.display = 'none'
        setTimeout(function () {
            const bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight
            const windowHeight = window.innerHeight
            if (bodyHeight < windowHeight) {
                footer.style.position = 'absolute'
                footer.style.bottom = '0'
                footer.style.width = '100%'
            }
            footer.style.display = 'block'
        }, 100) // Let the page load first
    }


Have you tried do achieve the same result using only CSS rules and without setting the footer's position absolute? Just wondering.

@AnnaK I tried to set the min-height of the body to 100vh but it moved all my other components and with my actual css config it's a mess. But more than that I want to understand how to deal with this kind of asynchronous problem.

What you want to achieve is called sticky footer. You can read more here.

@iseven, sure, for educational purpose it's fine, but honestly, it is NOT a right way to do such things...

This presently reads like an X-Y problem. "Help me climb the building to the top floor using my climbing boots:" when the answer might be "use the stairs".

@MarkSchultheiss Like I said I know it's not the right way I just wanted to know how to deal with such kind of asynchronous problem

So this doesn't help me about the asynchronous part but here is my fix for the footer in css.
:root {
  --header-height: 6.5rem;
  --footer-height: 5rem;
}

main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height) - var(--footer-height));
  padding: 40px 40px 0 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

I just add to add a main at my base Astro layout

You don't need to use JavaScript to do this effect.
Take a look at this for example:


function AddContentToExemple() {
  const contentElement = document.querySelector("main");
  contentElement.append("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum");
}
:root {
  --footer-height: 20px;
}

main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - var(--footer-height));
  padding: 40px 40px 0 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  height: var(--footer-height);
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
<main>
  <p>You can add text by clicking on the button bellow :</p>
  <button onclick="AddContentToExemple()">Add Content</button>
</main>
<footer class="footer">
  Footer
</footer>




I don't know what your CSS looks like but for the JS part:
You are using setTimeout to delay the execution of your logic/function.
I would recommend using Promise.resolve().
It is similar idea but little bit more elegant since rather than waiting for arbitrary time set in your setTimout function, it is scheduled to run in the next cycle of the event loop, after all the other functions on the stack trace have returned.
Your code would look like this:
 window.onload = function () {
        const footer = document.querySelector('footer')
        if (!footer) return
        footer.style.display = 'none'
        Promise.resolve(()=>{
            const bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight
            const windowHeight = window.innerHeight
            if (bodyHeight < windowHeight) {
                footer.style.position = 'absolute'
                footer.style.bottom = '0'
                footer.style.width = '100%'
            }
            footer.style.display = 'block'
          }
        ) // Let the page load first
}

Give it a go!

Since I believe the actual challenge appears to be getting a header/main/footer layout this can be so much simpler just using one line of CSS.  Comments in the CSS but the first section is the key for the container to set all three areas based on the child content of head/footer and the main gets all the rest.


.parent-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

/* everthing below here is just to show what is where */
.section {
  /* just to "super center" each section */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
.header.section {
  background-color: #FF000020;
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}
.main.section {
  background-color: #00FF0020;
}
.footer.section {
  background-color: #0000FF20;
  height: 3em;
}
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="header section" contenteditable>Header</div>
  <div class="main section" contenteditable>Main</div>
  <div class="footer section" contenteditable>Footer Content</div>
</div>




No sure if it will resolve your issue, but I would first try to use this event listener instead of window.onload:
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
      console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });


OP mentions that some content is being loaded in asynchronously. I'm not sure if DOMContentLoaded will trigger when this completes. (I didnt downvote, just commenting)
